# Spring & React - WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/' failed:

Tags: reactjs, spring, websocket

I am new to React, Spring and WebSocket and I'm trying to make a WebSocket using Spring to connect to the React app.
It works on Firefox but not on Chrome or Edge.

I can't modify the React app and the app connects with HTTP.

The configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketHandler(), "/");
    }
}
```

The SocketHandler class

```
@Component
public class SocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message)
            throws Exception {

        System.out.println("I received");
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hi how may we help you?"));
    }
}
```

I've tried to use certificates or org.springframework.security but none of it works.

Comment: Does your Spring application throw an Exception when accessed from Chrome or Edge? Does the React app output an error log to browser's console? If so, please show us the Exception or the error log.

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors in the React app output. Only Chrome and Edge show the error WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/' failed: